# Android Gradle Plugin Warning: string 'ucrop_error_input_data_is_absent' has no default translation

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to build my old react-native project which runs on react-native 0.56 and i get the above warning. Is this because i have not upgraded to androidx.  My Build.gradle(project) is given below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
           url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
         }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.0"
    firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
```

}

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```